# How to subtract values in many columns from last record and so on using awk?

Tags: awk

I need help with this script in AWK. 
For every field of every column, I would like to subtract value like this example:

```
2007 - 2004 = 3  
505 - 505 = 0
386 - 386 = 0
```

and so on next columns...

My file format is like bellow

```
20200224 09:00:50 1998 503 384 439 110 132 126 17 0 26 29 14 2 0 4 21 0 0
20200224 09:00:55 2003 503 386 440 110 132 126 17 0 26 29 14 2 0 4 21 0 0
20200224 09:01:00 2004 505 386 444 110 132 126 17 0 26 29 14 2 0 4 21 0 0
20200224 09:01:01 2007 505 386 446 110 132 126 17 0 26 29 14 2 0 4 21 0 0
```

Output format like that:

```
20200224 09:00:50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
20200224 09:00:55 5 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
20200224 09:01:00 1 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
20200224 09:01:01 3 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk one-liner will help you:

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){t[i]=$i;$i=NR==1?0:$i-a[i];a[i]=t[i]}}7' file
```

Test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
20200224 09:00:50 1998 503 384 439 110 132 126 17 0 26 29 14 2 0 4 21 0 0
20200224 09:00:55 2003 503 386 440 110 132 126 17 0 26 29 14 2 0 4 21 0 0
20200224 09:01:00 2004 505 386 444 110 132 126 17 0 26 29 14 2 0 4 21 0 0
20200224 09:01:01 2007 505 386 446 110 132 126 17 0 26 29 14 2 0 4 21 0 0

kent$  awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){t[i]=$i;$i=NR==1?0:$i-a[i];a[i]=t[i]}}7' f
20200224 09:00:50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
20200224 09:00:55 5 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
20200224 09:01:00 1 2 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
20200224 09:01:01 3 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```